# Hiding BitTorrent clients

Tags: p2p, torrent

One of the things that came out of the Snowden files, I believe, was that ISP's will monitor someone that has a BitTorrent client (uTorrent, qbittorrent etc.) installed on their PC, even if they don't use it. It is possible to hide BitTorrent *traffic* using a VPN, but, hypothetically, how does one hide the very existence of a BitTorrent client on their computer from potential snoopers?

Comment: Your bittorrent client isn't a service that they can go around scanning for, and ISPs certainly aren't going around hacking their customers computers (that I know of). Why doesn't downloading it with a VPN work or over HTTPS work? It's really impossible for an ISP to always tell what someone has on their computer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without a backdoor installed on your machine,  an attacker would not be able to know what software was installed. If 100% of your traffic passes though an encrypted VPN, then it is not possible for an ISP to know what data is being transmitted.  However, protecting the transport layer with a VPN may not conceal the type of protocol used to transmit the data.  Researchers have [claimed that it is possible to identify protocols protected by a VPN using statistical analysis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWCenXyoq1Q), and other reservedness claimed that it is possible to [identify encrypted BitTrorrent with information theory](http://www.salzburgresearch.at/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/master-thesis_dorfinger.pdf).

The only way for an ISP to know that a BitTorrent client was installed is by looking at the traffic it produces.  If at **any point** the client calls home to check for an update,  an observable condition has been created.  Participating in the [BitTorrent Distributed Hash Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332107/how-does-dht-in-torrents-work),  or visiting well known trackers is also a dead give away.  But even if the data is encrypted, looking at a **side-channel**,  such as comparing protocol timing signature,  could reveal the use of a P2P protocol.